# Single page navigation with flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to create a web app that only renders one page, and the other pages (or views) are rendered when you press a button related to that specific view. Like the [Flutter Gallery](https://gallery.flutter.dev/) website, when you click on a widget info in the "Categories" section

Is there any workaround for this or do I have to create my own router?

Answer (score 1):

you can keep all widgets on one page package by creating a switch statement in your build page. switch between different widget when rendering the scaffolding.

Comment: Pretty much like an IndexedStack I guess, I'll give it a try

Comment: Yes.  Most flutter controls use a model for controlling which widget to render.  In the case of bottomnavigationbutton an index is used to determine with widget to render in a switch statement